# how to make all the numbers add together till left with 1 digit number (in a list)

Tags: python-3.x

the program is suppose to ask for you full name and convert it to numbers then it will keep adding the numbers in the list till it gets a 1 digit number. I have finished the product and works just fine however it cannot add the third or more digits. please help. it says where i need help in the link

```
name1 = []  #its a list called name  
name1 = str(raw_input("Enter your first name and second name "))   #this code asks the user and saves the name as a list  
lettervalue =[]   
index=0
```

#

## THE CODE THAT CONVERTS THE NAME TO NUMBERS AND PUT IT IN A LIST

```
for index in range (len(name1)):                
  if name1 [index] == "a" or name1 [index] == "j" or name1 [index] == "s":                             
        lettervalue.append(1)                     
elif name1 [index] == "b" or name1 [index] == "k" or name1 [index] == "t":  
        lettervalue.append(2)
elif name1 [index] == "c" or name1 [index] == "l" or name1 [index] == "u":
    lettervalue.append(3)
elif name1 [index] == "d" or name1 [index] == "m" or name1 [index] == "v":
    lettervalue.append(4)
elif name1 [index] == "e" or name1 [index] == "n" or name1 [index] == "w":
    lettervalue.append(5)
elif name1 [index] == "f" or name1 [index] == "o" or name1 [index] == "x":
    lettervalue.append(6)
elif name1 [index] == "g" or name1 [index] == "p" or name1 [index] == "y":
    lettervalue.append(7)
elif name1 [index] == "h" or name1 [index] == "q" or name1 [index] == "z":
    lettervalue.append(8)
elif name1 [index] == "i" or name1 [index] == "r":
    lettervalue.append(9)
elif name1 [index] == " ":
    lettervalue.append(0)
index = index + 1
```

#

```
print lettervalue #prints the list to reduce confusion   

total1 = sum(lettervalue) #sums up the numbers in the list and turns it into a variable  
print total1     # also prints the total to reduce confusion
```

#

## A while loop that keeps adding each number until its left with 1 digit number (where i neeed help)

```
while total1 > 9:
split1 = 0
split2 = 0
total1 = str (total1)
split1 = total1[0]
split2 = total1[1]
total1 = int (split1) + int(split2)

print "your lucky number is " + str(total1)
```

#

## this code makes the final number to its charecteristics and prints it letteing them know their lucky number

```
if total1 == 1:
print "WOW you are a Natural leader!"
if total1 == 2:
print "WOW you are a Natural peacemaker!"
if total1 == 3:
print "WOW you are Creative and optimistic !"
if total1 == 4:
print "WOW you are a Hard worker!"
if total1 == 5:
print "WOW you Value freedom!"
if total1 == 6:
print "WOW you one of them who cares and provides!"
if total1 == 7:
print "WOW you are a Think!"
if total1 == 8:
print "WOW you have diplomatic skills!"
if total1 == 9:
print "WOW you are selfless and generous!"
```

Comment: post your code here..

Comment: ...using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33972704/edit) link on your question

Comment: i updated it, now u can check

Comment: Your indent is not correct, but this is a copy-past error, right?

Comment: yes it is, the indents are all right, the program works just fine

Comment: Do you mean adding numbers like this? 7+8+9 = 24; then 2+4 = 6

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i meant @VPfB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code addresses the problem with your while loop:

```
totals = []
total = sum(lettervalue)
while total > 9:
    breakdown = list(str(total))
    for i in breakdown:
        i = int(i)
        totals.append(i)
    total1 = sum(totals)
```

This works with the rest of your program. If there any further errors please don't hesitate to let me know with a comment.

**EDIT:** The `for i in breakdown` part of the code means for iteration in breakdown.

`Breakdown` is an array, and so it has values stored in it. The for loop just iterates through all of these values, and does the same process on each of them. So if `breakdown` contained the values "1, 2, 3, 4", the code would turn that number into an integer, and then append it to the totals array.

***Note:** This part of the code is necessary because it enables the `sum` function to work properly. List returns a string, not an integer, thus we need to change all the values into integers*

Comment: i do not understand the part where it says for i in breakdown

Comment: so i added this code, the the program doesnt work, it just converts the letters however doesnt do anything else like printing the number or convert it to the characteristics

Comment: @vairond Please could you add your full code to your question (not broken down into parts) so I could supply a full working example?

Comment: hey its kl, i found a way, thanks soo much for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this. Using a dictionary to map your letters to values you can iterate through the name and get the result quite easily. If a value in a name does not match a value in the dictionary then it will return 0.

I used `total % 10` to get total (mod 10) which will always be a single digit. This will also get 0 though if total = 10.

```
# dictionary of letter values
letter_dict = {'a': 1, 'j': 1, 's': 1,
              'b': 2, 'k': 2, 't': 2,
              'c': 3, 'l': 3, 'u': 3,
              'd': 4, 'm': 4, 'v': 4,
              'e': 5, 'n': 5, 'w': 5,
              'f': 6, 'o': 6, 'x': 6,
              'g': 7, 'p': 7, 'y': 7,
              'h': 8, 'q': 8, 'z': 8,
              'i': 9, 'r': 9}

# get name
name1 = str(raw_input("Enter your first name and second name "))

# For-loop | get list of values
# Using .get will return the value corresponding to the letter
# If not value matches eg. (' ', !, ' ) then 0 is returned
# .lower is used to include uppercase letters in result
letter_value = []
for s in name1:
    letter_value.append(letter_dict.get(s.lower(), 0))

# While loop
total = sum(letter_value)
while total > 9:
    total = sum(int(n) for n in str(total))

print "your lucky number is " + str(total)
```

Using list comprehension is generally a cleaner alternate method of using a for loop to append a value to a list. The for loop above can be replaced with this.

```
letter_value = [letter_dict.get(s.lower(), 0) for s in name1]
```

Comment: i dont really get this

Comment: i made an update since maybe you don't know what list comprehension is. But would you like to elaborate you what you don't understand so I can explain it?

Comment: This is essentially everything you want to do except print the characteristics

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what kind of error you're getting?

Comment: Ah sorry, it may have been because I posted `input` instead of `raw_input` I fixed the line in answer

Comment: @StevenSummers: please see the comments under the question above computing the "lucky" number. The while loop body should be something like `total = sum(int(n) for n in str(total))`